# Discord.js embed countdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, countdown

I need some help:
How am I able to create a embed that update itself every 2 seconds?

Info:
The embed should include a countdown of 3 days. Every two seconds the embed should update itself and goes down to 00:00:00. I would like to use the following method to get the message and update itself:

```
bot.guilds.cache.get('').channels.cache.get('').messages.fetch('');
```

Im really new to discord.js development and need some help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setInterval()` method to do this. What this does is run a block of code every ___ seconds. Using this, and a variable to store a Unix timestamp of when the timer will finish, we can update a message using the `.edit()` method, so it shows how much time is left.

```js
bot.on("ready", () => {
    // other code
    const message = bot.guilds.cache.get('').channels.cache.get('').messages.fetch('');
    let timeLeft = INSERT TIMESTAMP HERE;
    setInterval(() => {
        timeLeft -= 2000;
        message.edit(`There is ${timeLeft} time left!`):
    }, 2000)
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks! But there is an error:         message.edit(`There is ${timeLeft} time left!`);
                ^

TypeError: message.edit is not a function
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Replaysucht.de\discord\Bot_v2\index.js:245:17)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .

Answer (score 0):

Use markdown timestamp so you don't need to send requests from server every second.

Markup: `<t:1655196925:R>`

Check here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-formats